# Convert C++ routine to C#, primarily pointers

Tags: c#, c++

I am mainly a C++ programmer, but in my spare time I am attempting to come up to speed on C#.  I have the following C++ function that I would like to convert-

```
#define COMPUTE_CRC32(cp,crc) (crc32lookup_table[((unsigned long)crc^(unsigned char)cp)&0xff]^(((unsigned long)crc>>8)&0x00FFFFFF))

unsigned long ComputeCRC32::Update(const void* ptrBytes, long numBytes)
{
    const unsigned char* ptr_data = (const unsigned char*) ptrBytes;

    while ( --numBytes >= 0 )
    {
        unsigned char data_byte = *ptr_data++ ; 

        m_ulCRC = COMPUTE_CRC32( data_byte, m_ulCRC );
    }

    return m_ulCRC;
}
```

I know there are many ways to do this but would like to see what the best way was to do it.  This is what I have created so far -

```
public uint Update(object ptrBytes, int numBytes)
{
    byte * ptr_data = (byte) ptrBytes;

    while (--numBytes >= 0)
    {
        byte data_byte = *ptr_data++;

        m_ulCRC = (GlobalMembersComputeCRC32.crc32lookup_table[((uint)m_ulCRC ^ (byte)data_byte) & 0xff] ^ (((uint)m_ulCRC >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF));
    }

    return m_ulCRC;
}
```

What would be the best way to convert the pointers?  Is there a better way to rewrite this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is a language that has pointers, but also has references (and [references are not necessarily addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx)). An array such as `byte[]` in C# is the usual way of representing something you might use pointers for in C++.

To use pointers, you use [`unsafe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you are thinking in C#, people tend to avoid `unsafe` as it is generally "unsafe"; the runtime instead enforces checks to avoid things like buffer overruns in arrays. Instead, the psuedo code for Crc32 might be:

```
public uint Crc32(byte[] data) {
  uint result;
  for (int i= 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
    byte data_byte = data[i];
    result = doCrc(...stuff with data_byte...);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note that the `for` loop uses `data.Length` as its limit check (ref: [Eric Gunnerson: Efficiency of iteration over arrays](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/04/18/115566.aspx)), as this can be optimised by the JIT against the array length. If you use a separate length parameter it can't be, so this is to be avoided (or combined with length, if the required iteration count might be less than the array length).

Comment: Hats off to you and @paddy.  Your answers are pretty much the same and confirm that I was heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

These pointers are not doing anything tricky.  They're just array iterators.

```
public uint Update( byte[] ptrBytes, int numBytes )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++ )
    {
        byte data_byte = ptr_data[i];
        m_ulCRC = ...
    }

    return m_ulCRC;
}
```